# Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, module, discord.js

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
 throw err;
 ^

Error: Cannot find module 'better-sqlite3'
Require stack:
- D:\UserProfile\Users\Administrator\Desktop\rosbot\src\utils\db.js
- D:\UserProfile\Users\Administrator\Desktop\rosbot\src\Client.js
- D:\UserProfile\Users\Administrator\Desktop\rosbot\app.js
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
   at Object.<anonymous> (D:\UserProfile\Users\Administrator\Desktop\rosbot\src\utils\db.js:1:18)
   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19) {
 code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
 requireStack: [
   'D:\\UserProfile\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\rosbot\\src\\utils\\db.js',
   'D:\\UserProfile\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\rosbot\\src\\Client.js',
   'D:\\UserProfile\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\rosbot\\app.js'
 ]
}
```

I am getting this error when I am trying to run the discord bot with vscode by the command "node ." and I don't know how to solve this

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't Imported the module or named it wrong or installed

example to fix importing error:

```
const <name> = require("better-sqlite3");
```

example to fix name error:

```
const <name> = require("better-sqlite3");
```

example to fix installing error:

in cmd type: `npm i better-sqlite3`

after that type

```
const <name> = require("better-sqlite3")
```

change name with what you want it to be as.